# NullReferenceException when using NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm trying to set up unit tests for a card game application, but my code is throwing a NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. As far as I can tell I should not be getting this error, but there it is.

Here is my code:

```
        [TestFixture]
        public class Tests
        {
            CardTable aTable = null;

            [SetUp]
            public void setup()
            {
                aTable = new CardTable();
            }


            [Test]
            public void setPlayerGold_setTo0_return0()
            {
                //arrange

                //act
                aTable.setPlayerGold(0);


                //assert
                Assert.AreEqual(0, aTable.playerGold);
            }
       }

       public class CardTable
       {
           int playerGold;

           public CardTable()
           {
               playerGold = 0;
           }


            public void setPlayerGold(int amount)
            {
               if (amount == 0)
               {
                    playerGold = 0;
               }
               else
               {
                   playerGold += amount;
               }
               goldLabel.Text = playerGold + "";
            }
```

The exception gets thrown at the aTable.setup line as though aTable was not instantiated, even though it clearly was in the [Setup], and I can't figure out why.

I am running Visual C# 2010 Express v10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel with NUnit 2.6.0.12051.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: during debugging, does setup gets called?

Comment: Can we see the code of CardTable class ? It seems this setup crash.

Comment: @ykatchou, the CardTable class is not the issue as it works fine when run. The problem is that NUnit thinks that the CardTable aTable is never created. Also this is not really BlackJack and CardTable is about 3000 lines of code...

Comment: Are you sure this is your code? `player.hand.addCard(new Card(11);` is missing a parenthesis....

Comment: Are you sure the CardTable is really create during the Setup ?

Comment: I changed the code to simplify it, also I just woke up a half hour ago...I'm not perfect.

Comment: Try moving `aTable = new CardTable();` to the test method and see what happens.

Comment: @ykatchou, I also tried instantiating in the test method itself, same thing.

Comment: are you sure aTable != null ? just after the new ?

Comment: @peter9227 so it is not an nunit problem, you should betetr look in the stack trace where the NRE occours

Comment: Let me make this clear...the game works _fine_ when run in VS. I am trying to expand it, and need unit testing to prevent regression. It is the _unit tests_ that throw this error, not the game.

Comment: Could you create a new test that reproduces the error and paste that code instead of one new code summarizing the problem but that you didn't actually execute? It's a really weird situation and not having the actual code won't help. Thanks.

Comment: @ivowiblo I have updated the code to more accurately show what I am actually running. I'm sorry, I didn't realize this was a weird situation.      I removed the aTable.setup() call, but the NRE just gets thrown on the aTable.setPlayerGold(0) call instead.

Comment: When I _only_ run the assert line, the test passes, so aTable cannot be null, or the assert would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Start NUnit, but don't run the tests. In visual studio make sure you have the project that contains your nunit tests open. Then in visual studio press ctrl+alt+p. This will bring up the list of processes to attach to. Choose the nunit-agent.exe process. If there is more than one nunit-agent.exe process you can ctrl+ to choose all of them. You may have to check the *Show processes in all sessions* and/or *Show processes from all users* to get the nunit-agent.exe to show up. At this point you should be able to debug your test.

Now you can set a breakpoint at the constructor call to `CardTable`. As you step through the debugger you should be able to identify your null object reference error.

An alternative to stepping through the code is to choose in the menu *Debug->Exceptions...* in the dialog that shows check the thrown box next to *Common Language Runtime Exceptions*. This will cause the debugger to stop on any execptions handled or unhandled when they are thrown. This removes the need for the breakpoint, but if you have exceptions being thrown that are caught, it may be more hassle than the breakpoint method above.

Comment: the ctrl+alt+p shortcut didn't pull anything up. I am using an express version of VS, does that make a difference?

Comment: @peter9227 Yes, express versions of visual studio can't attach to process.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like setup is your problem, and it isn't being called when you want it to.

I recommend doing this:

```
CardTable aTable = new CardTable();
```

That way it won't ever be null.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i have rolled back NUnit framework version from 3.7.1 to 3.0.5 and now all works without exceptions.
Maybe you should roll back to one of the previous version of NUnit framework.